# Unable to read data afrom appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm sure I've got something basic wrong but I can't spot it, sorry. Stepping into the startup code suggests the appsettings.json is being correctly loaded, but the test class then gets null for the config class.

*Startup:*

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appSettings.json");
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
        services.AddSession();

        services.Configure<EnvironmentConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("EnvironmentConfig"));
    }
}
```

*ConfigTester:*

```
public class ConfigTester
{
    private readonly IOptions<EnvironmentConfig> _environmentConfig;

    public ConfigTester(IOptions<EnvironmentConfig> environmentConfig)
    {
        _environmentConfig = environmentConfig;
    }

    public string ConfigName()
    {
        return _environmentConfig.Value.Name;         //_environmentConfig.Value is set, but Name is null
    }
}
```

*EnvironmentConfig:*

```
public class EnvironmentConfig
{
    public string Name;

}
```

*appSettings.json:*

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "EnvironmentConfig": {
    "Name": "develop"
  }
}
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `IServiceCollection.Configure`, the [`ConfigurationBinder`](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/ConfigurationBinder.cs) class that ends up doing the work of binding the values in your `appSettings.json` file to your `EnvironmentConfig` class [only binds against properties](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/ConfigurationBinder.cs#L145). That means all you have to do is change your public *field* to a public *property*:

```
public class EnvironmentConfig
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line in your ConfigureServices method before you configure your Options using `serives.Configure<T>()`. To use the Options feature you have to enable it.

`services.AddOptions();`